# Mule exception after Jersey component

Tags: rest, jersey, mule, mime-types, camunda

During research for my MSC I'm facing a problem that I do not understand.
The scenario: starting a simple flow by calling a REST api.
The flow does setting a static payload and call another REST api.

If I call the following flow I got a exception:

```
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration_Inbound"
    host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration_Inbound" />

<http:request-config name="cam" host="localhost"
    port="8090" basePath="/engine-rest" doc:name="cam-connection" />

<flow name="receiveOrderFlowRest">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration_Inbound"
        path="/orderDomain/services/rest/*" doc:name="HTTP-Inbound" />

    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="de.tj.msc.orderDomain.services.rest.ReceiveOrderRestImpl" />
    </jersey:resources>

    <set-payload
        value="{}"
        doc:name="Set Payload" />


    <http:request config-ref="cam"
        path="process-definition/key/orderDomain-main/submit-form" method="POST"
        doc:name="cam-startNewProcess"
        parseResponse="false">

        <http:request-builder>
             <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
</flow>
```

Calling will result following exception:

```
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 415 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.validateResponse(DefaultHttpRequester.java:311)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:299)
at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:186)
```

If I remove the jersey-part of the flow OR the http-requeswt-part the resulting part of the flow works fine. Only both in combination is the problem.

The service "CAM" needs json as MIME type.

Is there a simple basic mistake that I did ?

I hope anybody could help me.
Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Based on the 415, you could try setting the mimeType on the set-payload:

```
<set-payload
        value="{}"
        doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/json" />
```

Or set the Content-type header explicitly:

```
<set-property value="application/json" propertyName="Content-type" doc:name="Property" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Sadly this did not helped.

I tried both options and combinations. But every time I use the jersey component that exception occurs. I can not see clearly if it is mule who is complaining 415 or Camunda. But if I do not set json, camunda complains. So I think it is Mule.

I have no idea how to move on. I hope you could share another idea with me.

Comment: When you call the Mule API, can you try adding the following header: Accept: application/json ?